# How to create an areas table using the following specification using sql?

Tags: sql, database

How to create a table  with the following specification ? Can anyone help me out please. Especially with the min and max constraint.

Table name : areas

```
 Name     Type   Size       Validation

 id     int       10        Primary Key
name    varchar   40    Not Null, Min 3 Max 40
do_id   int       10    Foreign Key (division_offices)
pincode int       10     not null min 6 max 6
```

Comment: MySQL is a product, SQL is a language.

Comment: isit vokay now. Btw do you have ans for my que?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can only give you an ANSI SQL standard answer, which may or may not work with dbms product you are using. So please tag with the dbms product you are using!

Comment: i want to execute in localhost... Tht's it

Comment: And which database product is in localhost?

Comment: wamp . Do u knw the ans r wht? am just asking an query to create an table with the above requirements

Comment: I can't help you as long as you don't tell which database product you are using... Can for example be MySQL, or MS SQL Server, or many others. Some more ANSI SQL standard compliant, some less...

Comment: Also, what does MIN and MAX mean for name and pincode? Is it min/max values or the min/max length of the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSI SQL answer:

```
create table areas
(id      int         Primary Key,
 name    varchar(40) Not Null check(length(name) >= 3),
 do_id   int         references division_offices,
 pincode int         not null check(pincode between 100000 and 999999)
)
```